# MySQL: How to select customers who purchased a product with addon accessory

Tags: mysql

Say I have table that looks like the following:

```
|CUSTOMER  |  PRODUCT | PURCHASE ID  | DATE       |
|1A        |  A       | 1234         | 01/01/2017 |
|1A        |  A1      | 12345        | 01/01/2017 |
|1B        |  A       | 5432         | 02/01/2017 |
|1B        |  B       | 54321        | 03/01/2017 |
|1B        |  C       | 43215        | 04/01/2017 |
|1C        |  A       | 6789         | 05/01/2017 |
|1C        |  A2      | 67891        | 05/01/2017 |
```

How would I select only customers who purchased a particular product with an add-on product. The main product is A, B or C, with the add-ones being A1, B1, or C1 etc. The add-on has to be purchased on the same date but can have a different purchase Id. I need to show all lines, both main product and the product add-on.

Comment: Thank you Button Monkey I have only an iPad available right now and though I was following instructions but evidently not. My apologies.

Comment: IMPORTANT QUESTION: Are `PRODUCT` codes really exactly 1 CHAR and addon exactly 1 Number? That is feasible, otherwise, much more complicated

Comment: Yes product A has add on codes a1, a2, a3 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approximation of what you'd need

```
SELECT * 
FROM sale_table S
JOIN sale_table as A
  ON A.CUSTOMER=S.CUSTOMER AND A.DATE=S.DATE AND
     A.PRODUCT<>S.PRODUCT AND
     A.PRODUCT LIKE CONCAT(S.PRODUCT,'%');
```

This doesn't check for **numeric** extensions, so `APP` and `APPLE` would be considered add-ons.